# Mono compiler (dmcs) how to reference DLL?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to compile an example C# code which makes use of `System.Web.HttpUtility`. This isn't linked in the core libraries, however, I have (I think so) a DLL that has this namespace, and it is here: `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Web.dll`.

I've tried:

```
$ dmcs ./UrlBuilder.cs -lib:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Web.dll
```

But that didn't help. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe `-lib` is meant to specify a path - a directory. Use `-r` to add the actual reference. So for example:

```
$ dmcs ./UrlBuilder.cs -r:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Web.dll
```

Or potentially:

```
$ dmcs ./UrlBuilder.cs -lib:/usr/lib/mono/4.0 -r:System.Web.dll
```

Or I'd actually *expect* this to be okay on its own:

```
$ dmcs ./UrlBuilder.cs -r:System.Web.dll
```

(As Mono should know where its own system libraries are.)